# Excel Macro: Need to convert number to text with no delimiters and no rounding of numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, delimiter

Need a bit of you excel gurus' help. I have a column which has the following data.

| COLUMN A |
| --- |
| 12,345,678.00 |
| 45,678,900.12 |
| 12,345.67 |
| 85,000.00 |

I need to convert this in the below format, with the zeroes being there after taking out the commas and the decimal.

| COLUMN A |
| --- |
| 1234567800 |
| 4567890012 |
| 1234567 |
| 8500000 |

I have tried using the SUBSTITUTE formula, plus tried the " ' ", also tried converting to text but couldn't arrive to a solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: With your current sample data, just multiply by 100?

Comment: Thanks BigBen, I just overlooked something this simple :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @BigBen suggest you can achieve your output multiplying by `100` if your data is true numbers. If they are stored as text still you can multiply by 100 as any arithmetic operation ***`(if stored texts are numeric digits only)`*** will automatically convert results as number. Just you need to format resulting cells as `General`, even not `Number` because `Number` format may put comma as decimal separator. Additionally you can use `Substitute()` function to eliminate comma (,) and dot (.) if they are stored as text. Again format your resulting cells as `General`. Try below formula-

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A7,",",""),".","")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @harun24HR, Just converting the format to general and multiplying it by 100 got me the correct answer :)